# Weight painting does not show weight colouring

Tags: weight-painting

I am going through Andrew Price' grass tuotrial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhYtJ_VmvXE) and I am stuck with painting weight onto the plane.

I've followed his steps inserting the plance and subdividing it into more vertices.

However brushing the plane object or using "Weight Gradient" does not make a difference, no colours are changed. The vertex group will be created and whatever vertices I was brushing on will be added to the group, but the weight colouring isn't shown.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The weight painting in the tutorial is applied to the particle density on the plane. He also does not add an armature in the video.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I am unsure what you mean, you can paint weights on a mesh regardless of the presence of an armature.

Comment: I seems like the weight is applied but Blender is not showing the weight colouring. I tested this by using the "Weight Gradient" tool and applying it to my plane.

The particles (grass) is now denser on one end of the plane than the other implying that the weight has been applied to the vertex group. However Blender is not showing the actual colouring of the weight. Everything stays blue.

Comment: there is an option in user_preferences->system->custom_weight_color see if you have changed(enabled) that ? it should be disabled

Comment: Checked it, but it wasn't set. I tried adding a custom weight paint range to see if that would work but all it does is show the first colour on the range so I kept it disabled.

Comment: It is definitely applying the weight, just not showing the colour scheme.

Comment: @Chautelly check if this is the case with other fresh files ,objects in the same scene , to narrow down the possibilities

Comment: It seems to be a bug of some kind. I tried the exact same thing on a Windows machine (I'm using Linux Mint 17) and it worked fine on that one.

Comment: I went into Edit Mode and toggled "Show Weights" under "Mesh Display" and this actually shows the weight gradient.

Comment: does that make it work for weight paint as well ?

Comment: No it makes no difference when I switch back to "Weight Paint" mode

Comment: you should submit a bug report if you can confirm the problem is present on another Linux_mint

Comment: Thanks, I will. I'm downloading some older versions to see when it stopped working. It's working fine in 2.57 so far.

Comment: I've filed a bug report. The issue starts at version 2.73.